# converting Ant to gradle regex expression task

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant

> > //How to Write below code in gradle 
> >           converting from ant to gradle

```
        <property name="abc" value="path/to/abc/file"/>
        <property name="pqr" value="path/to/pqr/file"/>
        <property name="xyz" value="path/to/xyz/file"/>

        <var name="myfiltersetTokens" value="abc,pqr,xyz"/>

 <for list="${myfiltersetTokens}" param="prop" >
            <sequential>
                <propertyregex property="@{prop}" input="${@{prop}}" override ="yes" regexp="^[ \s]+|[ \s]+$"   replace="" global="true" />
             </sequential>
 </for>
```

Comment: Specify your problem, please. What do you want to do?

Comment: @rbr94 trimming white spaces using regex in gradle while copying

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy & transform you can use [Copy.filter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#filter%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

Eg:

```
task copyAndTransform(type: Copy) {
    from 'path/to/abc/file'
    from 'path/to/pqr/file'
    from 'path/to/xyz/file'
    into 'someDir'
    filter { it.replaceAll('^[ \s]+|[ \s]+$', '') }
}
```

Comment: suppose i have any .xml, .css ,.jsp files like wise so on other file , which are on my root directory and from there i am copying file on some other D:\drivepath so while copying i want to remove blank or white spaces from all file in that case how it can be done using ur above example.

Comment: //    i tried this to remove space in .txt content file but it doesn't reflect myCopy<<
{
copy{
   from  'WebContent'
 into   build_root
 
 include   '**/*'
 include   '**/*.txt'    
 
 exclude   'help/**/*.html'
 exclude   '**/*.js'
 exclude   '**/*.dtd' 
 exclude   '**/*.jsp' 
 exclude   '**/*.css'
 exclude   'WEB-INF/web.xml'
 exclude   'META-INF/context.xml'  
 
 
 filter { it.replaceAll('^[\\s]+|[\\s]+$','')}
    
 
}